# How to populate the textInput based on the variable, value and condition selected from the dropdown in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a simple application where I would like to auto populate the textinput based on the variable, values and condition selected from the dropdown.

For suppose, if I want to filter the data based on mpg < 10.4 then I would like to select them from the variable, values and condition option and then auto populate the mpg < 10.4 in the filter option. And then when I click the load, this filter should subset the data.

Also, this filter should auto populate the values as I continue to select another condition, like mpg <= 10.4 & cyl==8.

What should I do?

Here is the code:

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(haven)
library(shinythemes)
library(DataExplorer)
library(labelled)
library(tidyverse)
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("spacelab"),

                # Application title
                titlePanel("DataView App"),

                # Show a plot of the generated distribution
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
                    fileInput("data",
                              "Upload the Data"),

                    textInput('tdata', 'Filter', value = NULL),
                    varSelectInput("variables1", "Choose the Variable to subset", NULL, selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE),
                    selectInput('var1', 'Select Values:', choices = '', selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
                    selectInput('cond1', 'Coondition:', choices = c('%in%', '<', '>', '<=', '>=', '!=', '&'), selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE),
                    varSelectInput("variables", "Variables to View: ", NULL, multiple = TRUE),
                    actionButton("load", "Load"),
                    h5(''),
                    verbatimTextOutput("input_dict")
                  ), #sidebarPanel

                  mainPanel(
                    tabsetPanel(id='dataset',
                                tabPanel('Basics', verbatimTextOutput("input_intro")),
                                tabPanel('Dataset', DTOutput("input_file")),
                                tabPanel('Summary', verbatimTextOutput("input_sum"))
                    ) #tabsetPanel
                  ) #mainPanel

                ) #sidebarpanel
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  sampled <- reactive({
    mtcars
  })

  observeEvent(input$variables1, {
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "var1", 'Select Values: ', choices = levels(as.factor(sampled()[[input$variables1]])), selected = NULL)

  })

  sampled2 <- reactive({
    # req(input$variables1, input$var1)
    if(input$variables1!='' & length(input$var1) > 0){
      sampled() %>% filter(CESEQ %in% input$var1)
    } else if (input$variables1!='' & length(input$var1)==0){
      sampled()
    }
  })

  observe({
    req(sampled())
    updateVarSelectInput(session, "variables", "Variables to View: ", sampled())
    updateVarSelectInput(session, "variables1", "Choose the Variable to subset", sampled())
  })

  nsampled <- reactive({
    # tdata2 <- unique(input$tdata)
    # input$saveFilterButton
    expre <- parse(text = input$tdata)
    if(input$tdata != '') {
      if (length(input$variables)==0) {
        sampled() %>%
          filter(eval(expre))
      } else {
        sampled() %>%
          filter(eval(expre)) %>% dplyr::select(!!!input$variables)
      }
    } else {
      if (length(input$variables)==0) {
        sampled()
      } else {
        sampled() %>% dplyr::select(!!!input$variables)
      }
    }
  }) %>%
  bindEvent(input$load)

  output$input_file <- renderDataTable({
    # tdata2 <- unique(input$tdata)
    # input$saveFilterButton
    expre <- parse(text = input$tdata)
    if(input$tdata != '') {
      if (length(input$variables)==0) {
        sampled() %>%
          filter(eval(expre))
      } else {
        sampled() %>%
          filter(eval(expre)) %>% dplyr::select(!!!input$variables)
      }
    } else {
      if (length(input$variables)==0) {
        sampled2()
      } else {
        sampled() %>% dplyr::select(!!!input$variables)
      }
    }
  }) %>%
    bindEvent(input$load)

  output$input_sum <- renderPrint({
    Hmisc::describe(nsampled())
  }) %>%
    bindEvent(input$load)

  output$input_dict <- renderPrint({
    labelled::generate_dictionary(nsampled()) %>% dplyr::select(variable, label, col_type)
  }) %>%
    bindEvent(input$load)


  output$input_intro <- renderPrint({
    nsampled2 <- DataExplorer::introduce(nsampled())
    nsampled3 <- nsampled2 %>% pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = 'name3', values_to = 'Value') %>%
      mutate(name2=stringr::str_to_sentence(name3), Name=stringr::str_replace_all(name2, '\\_', ' ')) %>%
      slice_head(n=5) %>% dplyr::select(Name, Value)
    nsampled3
  }) %>%
    bindEvent(input$load)

}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: just to clarify, you are wanting the car names to populate right?

Comment: i want to subset the data based on certain conditions which are based on selection from the dropdowns

Comment: that doesn't answer the question? What specifically would you want to autopopulate?

Comment: sure, I would like to update the text in the filter based on what i select from the `choose the variable to subset` dropdown, `select value` and `condition` dropdowns and that filter condition should subset the data

Comment: okay sure, but what precisely do you want to ***appear*** in the filter box? Like, give me an example. In the screenshot you posted, what should appear? Give an example

Comment: For suppose if i wish to select the variable `mpg` from the `choose the variable to subset` dropdown, and then select a certain value from the `select value` and then select a `<`  `condition` drop down, and if we wish to set another conditions that starts with `&` then we need to select another variable , value and condition and this whole thing we need to print it as text in filter and get the dataset subset. e.g., `mpg <= 10.4 & cyl==8`

Comment: jkatam I asked you three times a straight answer, and three times you didn't seem to answer. I don't know if there's something I'm missing but I can't help you if you can't provide a concrete example of a desired output. Best of luck! I can't help

Comment: Sorry Mark, but with all due respect i think i provided all the information that is required, i even provided the example `mpg <= 10.4 & cyl==8` which I would like to print in the filter option. Now i also provided the screenshot if that i what you are expecting

Answer (score 0):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("variable", "Variable", choices = c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3")),
  selectInput("value", "Value", choices = c("Value1", "Value2", "Value3")),
  selectInput("condition", "Condition", choices = c("Condition1", "Condition2", "Condition3")),
  textInput("textInput", "Text Input")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$variable, {
    # Update text input based on the selected variable
    if (input$variable == "Var1") {
      updateTextInput(session, "textInput", value = "Value for Var1")
    } else if (input$variable == "Var2") {
      updateTextInput(session, "textInput", value = "Value for Var2")
    } else if (input$variable == "Var3") {
      updateTextInput(session, "textInput", value = "Value for Var3")
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$value, {
    # Update text input based on the selected value
    if (input$value == "Value1") {
      updateTextInput(session, "textInput", value = "Value for Value1")
    } else if (input$value == "Value2") {
      updateTextInput(session, "textInput", value = "Value for Value2")
    } else if (input$value == "Value3") {
      updateTextInput(session,
```

That code should work. It is based on the selected values from a dropdown menu using the `updateTextInput` function